# How to add layered navigation in Magento 2 on Top After Menu

Tags: magento2, xml, layered-navigation, page-layouts, theme-overriding

I tried to move **layered navigation** from `left-side to top` of the products.But Nothing displays When I changed the page layout from **2 column layout** to **1 column layout** then it shows only product list.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. **If you want it to be applied into a single category page only then perform following things**

> Go to your `Admin_Panel > Catalog > Category > Desired_Category >
>   Design` Put there below things at appropriate places
>
> **Layout >** `1 Column`
>
> **Layout Update XML >** `<move element="sidebar.main" destination="content" before="-"/>`

2. **To apply this to the entire categories just perform the below things**

Just go to the below place

```
Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/Layout/
```

Create a file there with the name `catalog_category_view.xml` & put the below code there into that file & save it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <move element="sidebar.main" destination="content" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then reload your frontend category page you will see your required view there

> **Note:** Do not forget to put your **cache disabled** or to perform the below
>   command from your **magento_root** after doing this changes into your
>   magento
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> ```
>
> **Most Important** -Never do changes into the core files of magento

Comment: fine. Now it is working..

Comment: Hey @Satendra still facing any issue then let me know :) !

Comment: Currently, I have no issue if any then tell you.

Comment: Hi @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI I have the same problem
I follow the steps but still not work for me.
Can you please let me know how we can identify this element="sidebar.main" because when I check my theme I got this element="div.sidebar.main"
but after using both still not work
please help me

Comment: @SatendraTyagi `element="sidebar.main"` is the element from the **Luma theme** If you are not having the same element in your theme then may be some other element is replace with it just search there in your theme that `element="sidebar.main"` have **`remoe="true"`** somewhere? & any other element is place into its place

Comment: The other thing just provide the access of your site & the content of **`catalog_category_view.xml`** of your theme.

Comment: Hello ABHISHEK its working but products are not showing on product listing page

Comment: Do they were showing previously? What error you are facing?